# Requirement VS Requisite

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference, adjectives

Could anyone please let me know how the following examples differ in meaning?

- Money is a **[requirement](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/requirement)** for life.
- Money is a **[requisite](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/requisite)** for life.

[Requirement:](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/requirement)
something that you must do, or something you need.

[Requisite:](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/requisite)
necessary or needed for a particular purpose.

To me, they both mean the same here, however this thread made me think there is a nuance between the two which makes one choice always sound better.

The only thing that crosses my mind is that "requisite" as a rare word sounds more formal.

The same goes in the following sentences as well:

- Latin is no longer a **[requirement](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/requirement)** for entry to university.
- Latin is no longer a **[requisite](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/requisite)** for entry to university.

Comment: *Requisite* can be an adjective. *Requirement* can't.

Comment: _Requisite_ is an old-fashioned word that has gradually declined in usage since the 1850s (according to Oxford Dictionaries). It makes me think of the (also rather old-fashioned) expression _toilet requisites_ for soap, toothpaste etc.

Comment: @KateBunting a female friend grew friendly with the little girls next door. They came to tea and were shown around the house. They were fascinated by her dressing table. 'What's in that bottle?' one asked. 'Toilet water' replied my friend. 'YUK!' they both exclaimed.

Comment: I agree with the others that "requisite" is rarely heard as a noun (and not particularly often as an adjective, either, I would add).  However, "prerequisite" is common and particularly appropriate for your last example: "Latin is no longer a prerequisite for entry to university."